# How can I change the maximum number of players in my server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am hosting a Counter Strike Go server. The problem is that its maxplayers is set to 64 which my PC simply cannot handle. This is causing the server to lag and run poorly when it becomes full.

How can I change the maximum number of players on my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the GUI to launch the server, there should be an option to change the maximum number of players in the first window you see when launching the server.

If you're using command line or a shortcut to launch the server, you can add `+maxplayers #` at the end of the line/shortcut target to launch the server with max players set to #, where # is the desired max number of players.

You may also want to [elevate priority](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Process-Priorities-in-Windows-Task-Manager) for the server to Above Normal to make it perform better when you have many programs running simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the `maxplayers` launch / command-line parameter has been deprecated. The `maxplayers` variable should now be set in `gamemodes_server.txt.example` (which should then be renamed to `gamemodes_server.txt`), or through the `-maxplayers_override` [launch/command-line parameter](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Source_Games), instead.

About gamemodes_server.txt:

> *This file must be created or otherwise generated from* `gamemodes_server.txt.example` *under the* `\csgo\` *folder.* This
>   file allows the server administrator to customize each game mode for
>   their own server. It overrides and defaults set by Valve in
>   gamemodes.txt. With this file, for example, you can change the
>   maxrounds for a game type from the default, or enable friendly fire
>   but reduce the amount of damage friendlies deal.
>
> *IT IS IMPORTANT TO MAINTAIN THE SAME HIERARCHY AND SYNTAX AS GAMEMODES.TXT!!!* Included with your server installation is a gamemodes_server.txt.example file to help you learn the syntax. There is no file specifically named gamemodes_server.txt in the standard server install. You must rename, copy, or make a new file called gamemodes_server.txt to be able to customize your game modes.

<sup>Source: "[Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Dedicated Servers - Advanced Configuration](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers#Advanced_Configuration)" article, Valve Developer Community wiki</sup> 
See the '[Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Dedicated Servers Known Issues - Maxplayers doesn't work/is overridden](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers_Known_Issues#Maxplayers_doesn.27t_work.2Fis_overridden)' article at the Valve Developer Community wiki, for more info.

Also, CS:GO's priority can be elevated through the launch / command-line parameter, `-high`, which will make the computer prioritize its CPU resources for CS:GO, improving performance. See the '[Command Line Options - Source Games](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Source_Games)' article at the Valve Developer Community wiki, for more info.